# What is the difference between "appreciation" and "gratitude"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, etymology, synonyms, linguistics

Should I be appreciative of, or be grateful to, what my parents do for me, when they both mean "thankful"? Is there a difference in between?
How is the difference identified?

Any efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: "Appreciation" doesn't necessarily mean "thankful".  I may appreciate the fact that a particular politician is an idiot, but that doesn't mean I'm thankful for it.

Comment: @HotLicks -  Well illustrated!

Comment: @Hot Licks yeah, you are right, but there are also instances when only one of its meanings is used, like "Much appreciated, bro", where it means only thankfulness.

Answer (score 3):

Both words are, of course, "distant" synonyms with one another.

The meaning of the word Gratitude has a very direct distinction of being used in regards to being "thankful" and is almost devoutly used to express, in one way or another, a sense of pleased "appreciation" for kindness. The literal etymological origin of the word comes from "Gratus" a Latin word meaning "to be pleased" or "thankful", and undoubtedly when reading the word "gratitude" the human mind is reminded of "grace"--it is a truly beautiful word.

Merriam Webster puts:

> the state of being grateful : THANKFULNESS

And Online Etymology Dictionary puts:

> mid-15c., "good will," from Middle French gratitude (15c.) or directly from Medieval Latin gratitudinem (nominative gratitudo) "thankfulness," from Latin gratus "thankful, pleasing" (from suffixed form of PIE root *gwere- (2) "to favor"). Meaning "thankfulness" is from 1560s.

Whilst, in a distinguished distinction, the word appreciate, although it could be used in context to be "thankful" (as you sort of inferred to), also may mean to merely recognize or pay respects (admiration) towards a thing's, or person's value (if those values are virtuous or not, the word innately does not distinguish that). But then again it may also mean to recognize (acknowledge) the implications or contexts of a situation; whether that recognition is of a goodly nature or whether it is of a malignant or neutral nature matters not anywhere other than the context of the word's use.

Merriam Webster puts:

> to grasp the nature, worth, quality, or significance of
> appreciate the difference between right and wrong
> B : to value or admire highly
> She appreciates our work.
> C : to judge with heightened perception or understanding : be fully aware of
> must see it to appreciate it
> D : to recognize with gratitude

And OED puts:

> c. 1600 "act of estimating the quality and worth of something," from French appréciation, noun of action from apprécier (14c.), from Late Latin appretiare "estimate the quality of" (see appreciate). Generally with a sense of "high estimation" after c. 1650; "expression of (favorable) estimation" is from 1858.

In other words, "appreciation" is a more vague and open word that has room to be widely liberalized in the context of whatever it is one desires to convey. While, "gratitude" is almost always used in the context of a "milk of human kindness"-esque sense. "Appreciation" is based on "value", what that value entails is up to he/she who holds the pen to decide on.

Interestingly enough, since you used "etymology" as a tag of yours, I thought I would show how the Bard, himself, used the words, and found, much to the intrigue of my delighting eyes (delighting at the poetry), he never once uses the word "appreciate" or "appreciation". He does however use "gratitude" numerous times, and "ingratitude" even more so, and they all have a "kind" or "thankful" connotation to them:

From All's Well That Ends Well
(IV, 4, line 2423)

> Time was, I did him a desired office,
> Dear almost as his life; which **gratitude**
> Through flinty Tartar's bosom would peep forth,
> And answer, thanks:

Comment: Mr. O'Bedlam, thank you very much for the answer, wish you a nice day~~

Comment: @Student my pleasure.